# TypeError: can only join an iterable (testing invoking a SageMaker endpoint for computer vision classification)

Tags: python, typeerror, amazon-sagemaker

I built an out-of-box [CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) and deployed using AWS Step Functions. I have these custom functions for the endpoint:

```
def input_fn(data, content_type):
    '''
    take in image
    '''
    if content_type == 'application/json':
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
        img_arr = np.array(img)
        resized_arr = cv2.resize(img_arr, (img_size, img_size))
        return resized_arr[None,...]
    else:
        raise RuntimeException("{} type is not supported by this endpoint.".format(content_type))



def model_fn():
    '''
    Return model
    '''

    client = boto3.client('s3')
    client.download_file(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Key='model/kcvg_cv_model.h5', Filename='kcvg_cv_model.h5')
    model = tf.keras.saving.load_model('kcvg_cv_model.h5')

    return model

def predict_fn(img_dir):
    model = model_fn()
    data = input_fn(img_dir)
    prob = model.predict(data)
    return np.argmax(prob, axis=-1)
```

When I run this code

```
from sagemaker.predictor import RealTimePredictor
from sagemaker.serializers import JSONSerializer

endpoint_name = 'odi-ds-belt-vision-cv-kcvg-endpoint-Final-Testing4'

# Read image into memory
payload = None
with open("117.jpg", 'rb') as f:
    payload = f.read()

predictor = RealTimePredictor(endpoint_name = endpoint_name, sagemaker_session=sm_sess, serializer=JSONSerializer)
inference_response = predictor.predict(data=payload)
print (inference_response)
```

I get the following error

```
The class RealTimePredictor has been renamed in sagemaker>=2.
See: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v2.html for details.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 11
      8     payload = f.read()
     10 predictor = RealTimePredictor(endpoint_name = endpoint_name, sagemaker_session=sm_sess, serializer=JSONSerializer)
---> 11 inference_response = predictor.predict(data=payload)
     12 print (inference_response)

    File ~/anaconda3/envs/odi-ds/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker/base_predictor.py:177, in Predictor.predict(self, data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id, custom_attributes)
        129 def predict(
        130     self,
        131     data,
       (...)
        136     custom_attributes=None,
        137 ):
        138     """Return the inference from the specified endpoint.
        139
        140     Args:
       (...)
        174             as is.
        175     """
    --> 177     request_args = self._create_request_args(
        178         data,
        179         initial_args,
        180         target_model,
        181         target_variant,
        182         inference_id,
        183         custom_attributes,
        184     )
        185     response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
        186     return self._handle_response(response)

    File ~/anaconda3/envs/odi-ds/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker/base_predictor.py:213, in Predictor._create_request_args(self, data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id, custom_attributes)
        207     args["EndpointName"] = self.endpoint_name
        209 if "ContentType" not in args:
        210     args["ContentType"] = (
        211         self.content_type
        212         if isinstance(self.content_type, str)
    --> 213         else ", ".join(self.content_type)
        214     )
        216 if "Accept" not in args:
        217     args["Accept"] = self.accept if isinstance(self.accept, str) else ", ".join(self.accept)

    TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

I am guessing there is something I am doing wrong in the `input_fn`, but I am not exactly sure. What could it be?

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77108320/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without actually running the code, I suspect that the data is not communicated properly, i.e. you send binary file as textual JSON and it is not encoded correctly. I believe that following [AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/neo-requests-sdk.html) and specifying `content_type='application/x-image'` might help.

Another (minor) issue is that `RealTimePredictor` was deprecated in Sagemaker v2. The API varies based on the SageMaker SDK for Python version:

For version 1.x, use the RealTimePredictor and [older Predict](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/v1.72.0/api/inference/predictors.html#sagemaker.predictor.RealTimePredictor.predict) API.

```
predictor = RealTimePredictor(endpoint=endpoint, content_type='application/x-image')
inference_response = predictor.predict(data=payload)
```

For version 2.x, use the [Predictor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/predictors.html#sagemaker.predictor.Predictor) and the Predict API.

```
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor

...    
predictor = Predictor(endpoint)
inference_response = predictor.predict(data=payload)
```

Now, in the deployed model there are some inconsistencies with the Sagemaker API. You don't need to call the functions explicitly, the API does it upon request.

The `input_fn()` should return data ready for being used by the model (usually it is of Tensor type) and also it should not call the `predict_fn` by itself, as it is done by the API:

```
def input_fn(data, content_type):
    if content_type == 'application/x-image':
    ....
    return input_object # << data in the format the model is expecting
```

Predict function should be declared as `predict_fn(input_object, model)`, where `input_object` is the output of the `input_fn()` and model is the result of `model_fn()`, i.e. you do not have to call them explicitly.

And finally, you should serialize the result of the `predict_fn` to JSON so it can be accepted by the predictor, something like:

```
def output_fn(predictions, response_content_type):
    return json.dumps(predictions)
```

See [this notebook](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_batch_transform/pytorch_mnist_batch_transform/pytorch-mnist-batch-transform.ipynb) for reference.